# Cisco IOS subnet mask using bit notation

Tags: networking, cisco, router, ios

I was wondering if it was possible to use bit notatiton when configuring interfaces, or just in general, within the CISCO IOS. I have friends and others swear that they've been able to before, but not able to remember how. I get errors when attempting so I was thinking maybe there's  a command to enable it if it's possible.

Example:

```
Router(config-router)# ip address 172.16.0.1 /30
```

Comment: That's actually called CIDR notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CIDR notation can be used in IOS on prefix-lists, but not on interface or routing protocol configuration. Cisco does support CIDR notation more broadly in NX-OS on the new Nexus products.